# extjs app will not start after creating it in Architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I created an app in the Sencha Architect. I made the stores and models as well and the viewport is the initialview. When I test it now in firefox I get an error:

> "c is not a constructor"

and nothing happens. There is a lots of files generated but one file generated called app.js contains this:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
models: [
    'providerModel',
    'schedulingModel'
],
stores: [
    'comboboxProviders',
    'gridScheduling',
    'comboboxDriver',
    'comboboxVehicle',
    'comboboxStop',
    'gridLiveMapVehicles',
    'gridConfigurationProviders',
    'comboboxVehicleType',
    'comboboxVehicleProvider',
    'gridConfigurationVehicles',
    'gridConfigurationDrivers',
    'gridConfigurationStops',
    'gridConfigurationRoutes',
    'comboboxTimezone',
    'comboboxRoutes',
    'gridConfigurationRouteXYZ',
    'gridConfigurationDepots',
    'gridConfigurationOperationalDay',
    'gridConfigurationOperationalHour',
    'comboboxClockType',
    'comboboxSpeedFormat',
    'comboboxScheduleMode'
],
autoCreateViewport: true,
name: 'MyApp'
});
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: That's not very helpful. It's unlikely the error coming from this file. Can you see the stack when error happens?